# Safe search&replace on linux

Tags: regex, search, replace, sed, grep

Let's consider I have files located in different subfolders and I would like to search, test and replace something into these files.

I would like to do it in three steps:

1. Search of a specific pattern (with or without regexp)
2. Test to replace it with something (with or without regexp)
3. Apply the changes only to the concerned files

My current solution is to define some aliases in my `.bashrc` in order to easily use `grep` and `sed`:

```
alias findsrc='find . -name "*.[ch]" -or -name "*.asm" -or -name "*.inc"'
alias grepsrc='findsrc | xargs grep -n --color '
alias sedsrc='findsrc | xargs sed '
```

Then I use

1. `grepsrc <pattern>` to search my pattern
2. (no solution found yet)
3. `sedsrc -i 's/<pattern>/replace/g'`

Unfortunately this solution does not satisfy me. The first issue is that sed touch all the files even of no changes. Then, the need to use aliases does not look very clean to me.

Ideally I would like have a workflow similar to this one:

Register a new context:

```
$ fetch register 'mysrcs' --recurse *.h *.c *.asm *.inc
```

Context list:

```
$ fetch context
 1. mysrcs --recurse *.h *.c *.asm *.inc
 Extracted from ~/.fetchrc
```

Find something:

```
$ fetch files mysrcs /0x[a-f0-9]{3}/
./foo.c:235     Yeah 0x245
./bar.h:2       Oh yeah 0x2ac hex
```

Test a replacement:

```
$ fetch test mysrcs /0x[a-f0-9]{3}/0xabc/
./foo.c:235     Yeah 0xabc
./bar.h:2       Oh yeah 0xabc hex
```

Apply the replacement:

```
$ fetch subst --backup mysrcs /0x[a-f0-9]{3}/0xabc/
./foo.c:235     Yeah 0xabc
./bar.h:2       Oh yeah 0xabc hex 

Backup number: 242
```

Restore in case of mistake:

```
$ fetch restore 242
```

This kind of tools look pretty standard to me. Everybody needs to search and replace. What alternative can I use that is standard in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a tool doing exactely that you are looking for. This is `Git`. Why do you want to manage the backup of your files in case of mistakes when specialized tools can do that job for you?

You split your request in 3 subquestions:

- How quickly search into a subset of my files?
- How to apply a substitution temporarly, then go back to the original state?
- How to substitute into your subset of files?

We first need to do some jobs in your workspace. You need to init a Git repository then add all your files into this repository:

```
$ cd my_project
$ git init
$ git add **/*.h **/*.c **/*.inc 
$ git commit -m "My initial state"
```

Now, you can quickly get the list of your files with:

```
$ git ls-files
```

To do a replacement, you can either use `sed`, `perl` or `awk`. Here the example using `sed`:

```
$ git ls-files | xargs sed -i -e 's/search/replace/'
```

If you are not happy with this change, you can roll-back anytime with:

```
$ git checkout HEAD
```

This allows you to test your change and step-back anytime you want to.

Now, we did not simplified the commands yet. So I suggest to add an alias to your Git configuration file, usually located here `~/.gitconfig`. Add this:

```
[alias]
sed = ! git grep -z --full-name -l '.' | xargs -0 sed -i -e
```

So now you can just type:

```
$ git sed s/a/b/
```

It's magic...

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/ksh

# Call the batch with the 2 (search than replace) pattern value as argument

# assuming  the 2 pattern are "sed" compliant regex
SearchStr="$1"
ReplaceStr="$2"

# Assuming it start the search from current folder and take any file
# if more filter needed, use a find before with a pipe
grep -l -r "$SearchStr" . | while read ThisFile
 do
    sed -i -e "s/${SearchStr}/${ReplaceStr}/g" ${ThisFile}
 done
```

should be a base script to adapt to your need

Comment: Writing a script to do my search/replacement was one of my first ideas . Actually I was doing it with perl. But I have also the feeling that after more than 40 years the unix/linux tools should have powerful tools that not request to adapt a base script all the time. Don't you think so ?

Comment: just use a script that allow comment and easy modification on several specific case but after long experience, like your, unix tools are pretty well handed, that is not already the case of new comer especially starting from GUI and wizard. In this case, script secure a bit their action (still a bit of fear using a rm -fr in direct command line where a missing space or extra one could have very sad effect :-D )

Answer (score 2):

I often have to perform such maintenance tasks. I use a mix of `find`, `grep`, `sed`, and `awk`.

And instead of aliases, I use functions.

For example:

```
# i. and ii.
function grepsrc {
    find . -name "*.[ch]" -or -name "*.asm" -or -name "*.inc" -exec grep -Hn "$1"
}

# iii.
function sedsrc {
    grepsrc "$1" | awk -F: '{print $1}' | uniq | while read f; do
        sed -i s/"$1"/"$2"/g $f
    done
}
```

Usage example:

```
sedsrc "foo[bB]ar*" "polop"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for F in $(grep -Rl <pattern>) ; do sed 's/search/replace/' "$F" | sponge "$F" ; done
```

- `grep` with the `-l` argument just lists files that match
- We then use an iterator to just run those files which match through sed
- We use the `sponge` program from the `moreutils` package to write the processed stream back to the same file

This is simple and requires no additional shell functions or complex scripts.

If you want to make it safe as well... check the folder into a Git repository. That's what version control is for.